# ubuntu c++ how get the name of the current active keyboard

Tags: c++, ubuntu, keyboard, gdk

In Ubuntu C++ how **can I get the name of the current keyboard?**

I want to use a **c++ program** not the command line.

Answer (score 1):

For a proper solution you can use D-bus (used for inter-process communication)

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libdbus-cpp-dev
```

Alternatively you can try a bit of a hacky solution by installing and adding
`xkblayout-state` to your path and then have a C++ wrapper:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::system("xkblayout-state print \"%s\"");
    return 0;
}
```

The above will print out the layout of the keyboard.

Comment: I would say both solutions still use the command line and neither store the name of the keyboard in something representing a C++ string. So this is not an answer

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a library that would be designed for this task in C/C++. C++ wouldn't have a way of knowing a keyboard that is attached to the system.